# CSS - AOS animate library - why is slide-in animation distroying my width of entire page?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am using AOS library for animations. When I use the animation slide-left and slide-right, the width of the page becames wider that the body width, making the whole page look weird. I couldnt find any solution online and the only solution I figured out is if I give the elements which I apply the animation on a width in px (it cannot be bigger than 400px for whatever reason). However, that solution doesnt really work as it destroys up my css too. I have provided a js fiddle so you can see what I mean. Ive been spending hours on that so if anyone can help, I would be truly happy! Thanks!!

https://jsfiddle.net/Lca8n0ue/

code:

```
<div style="background-color:red; height:300px;"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row center-block wrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-6 test" data-aos="slide-right">
      <h2 class="text-center">title</h2>
      <p class="text-center">app</p>
      <div>
        <img class="img-fluid center-block" width="350" height="320" src="http://unsplash.imgix.net/reserve/9Fx2auQ4yoHM8OpWA8qw__MG_5265.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 test2" data-aos="slide-left">
      <h2 class="text-center">title</h2>
      <p class="text-center">appp</p>
      <div>
        <img class="img-fluid center-block" width="350" height="320" src="http://unsplash.imgix.net/reserve/9Fx2auQ4yoHM8OpWA8qw__MG_5265.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050" alt="">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 test" data-aos="slide-right">
      <h2 class="text-center">title</h2>
      <p class="text-center">app</p>
      <div>
        <img class="img-fluid center-block" width="350" height="320" src="http://unsplash.imgix.net/reserve/9Fx2auQ4yoHM8OpWA8qw__MG_5265.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 test2" data-aos="slide-left">
      <h2 class="text-center">title</h2>
      <p class="text-center">appp</p>
      <div>
        <img class="img-fluid center-block" width="350" height="320" src="http://unsplash.imgix.net/reserve/9Fx2auQ4yoHM8OpWA8qw__MG_5265.jpg?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050" alt="">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

AOS.init();

ONLY THING THAT HELPS BUT RUINS CSS IS:

```
.test{
  width: 400px;
}

.test2{
  width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I'm not completely sure **WHY** is it so (I had the same problem a lot of time) there is another way to fix this.

Just set `overflow-x: hidden` on the parent element.

In your case this would be `.container-fluid`.

Comment: Thank you so so so much!!! Ive spend hours trying to figure it out, actually trying other libraries too, only to see that the problem with the width occurs with any library as long as the animation is slide in and on scroll, but setting overflow-x to hidden works PERFECT!!! Thanks!!!!